# input ouput functions in c

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char s[20];
    for(int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        printf("enter a name \n ");        // printf & scanf
        scanf("%s",&s);
        printf("the names are %s \n",s);
    }
    for(int j=1;j<=3;j++)
    {
        puts("enter a name \n ");
        gets(s);                           // puts and gets
        puts(s);
    }
    char ch='a';
    putchar(ch);                           // putchar and getchar
    ch = getchar();
    getch();
}
```

There is a repetition (three times) of the printf statement...can anyone explain this?

The output is like this:

```
enter name
my name is alex
the names are my
enter a name
the names are name
enter a name
the names are is
enter a name
 alex
enter a name
alex again
enter a name
alex twice
alex twice
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&s);` -> `scanf("%s",s);`

Comment: you mean the print statements in your for loops that run from 1 -> 3? Why wouldn't they be output three times?

Comment: @AlterMann: `s` is an array so it makes no difference.

Comment: You should limit the user input to your buffersize. Have a look at `fgets()` or the maximum field width parameter for `scanf()`.

Comment: You probably want to scan until a line break, so you don’t scan word for word.

Comment: @barakmanos, true, but it makes the compiler happy :P

Comment: now i have provided the output too...sry its nt in much readable form.....

Comment: To read a line of user input, recommend `fgets()` rather than `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scanf` with `%s` will read until the first whitespace character. So your input `my name is alex` is read over the space of 4 calls to `scanf`, which will make your output look strange. You might want to consider using the function `getline` if you want to read until the end of a line (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)

Note that this was originally also tagged as c++, so I assume the OP can use c++ libs as well.

Comment: if its doesnt read spaces it should stop at "my"...rather than again displaying "name" "is" "alex"..

Comment: @user3763047 It does stop at "my", the first time. You call `scanf` multiple times though, each one will read the next word of your input (which is growing much more quickly than you are consuming)

Comment: "scanf with %s will read until the first whitespace character" is not so.  "scanf with %s" will 1) first read and discards any whitespace, then 2) will read and save `char` until the first whitespace character 3) then put that last whitespace back into `stdin` for subsequent input and 4) append a '\0' to the destination.